# Determine the sum value of the first terms of that sequence.

Tags: geometric-progressions

Consider a  geometric progression in which the common ratio  is a non-zero natural number, knowing that the logarithm of the nth term at the base equal to the common ratio  of the sequence is equal to 6, that the logarithm of the product of the first n terms at the base equal to that of the sequence is equal to 20 and that the product between the first and the nth term of the sequence is equal to 243, determine the sum value of the first terms of that sequence.

I imagine I have to use the logarithm formulas but I can't equalize them

$ S_n = a_1 \cdot \frac{q^{n}-1}{q-1}\\
P_n = a_1^n . q^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}\\
$

Comment: I assume that the sequence has form $~~a, aq, aq^2, aq^3, ...~~$I am guessing that you tried to faithfully present the problem as you found it.  Personally, I can't attack it because I can't decipher the following: $$\text{that the logarithm of the nth term at the base equal to the common ratio of the sequence is equal to 6}$$ or $$\text{the logarithm of the product of the first n terms at the base equal to that of the sequence is equal to 20}.$$ Also, since I prefer not to guess, how would you interpret $$\text{the product between the first and the nth term of the sequence is equal to 243}?$$

Comment: $ q = \text{common ratio} \\ log_q  a_n=6\\
log_q\underbrace{ (a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot a_3...)}_n=20\\
a_1 \cdot a_n =243 $

Comment: For what it's worth: [1] I found that there are two distinct values for $(n)$ that can satisfy the constraints, each of which leads to a different final answer. [2] I solved the problem, under the assumption that "determine the sum value of the first terms of that sequence" refers to the first $n$ terms of the sequence.  However, MathSE protocol, prevents me from posting an answer, because you haven't edited your query to show work.  See, for example [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).  ...see next comment

Comment: If you do decide to edit your query, to show an attempt to solve the problem, please flag me with a comment.  Then, I will look at your work, and (presumably) then post my answer, if no one else already has.

Comment: By the way: re my 2nd to last comment: I overlooked the constraint that $(q)$ is required to be an integer.  Because of this constraint, there is only one solution.

Comment: I try  = $ \text{common ratio} \\ log_q  a_n=6\\ log_q\underbrace{ (a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot a_3...)}_n=20\\  $

Comment: I try  = $ (a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot a_3 = q^20\\ \therefore q^20 = a_1^n .q^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}  $ But I can't see how to equalize the equations ...I appreciate if I can help, but ok, stay for the next one

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Constraints:**

- Assume that $a = a_1$, which is the first term in the sequence.
- The sequence is geometric, with common ratio $q \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
- $\log_q (a_n) = 6.$
- $\log_q (a_1 \times a_2 \times \cdots \times a_n) = 20.$
- $a_1 \times a_n = 243.$

**Goal**: Compute $(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n)$.

---

$\displaystyle q^6 = a_n = aq^{(n-1)} \implies a = q^{7-n}.$

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (k) = \frac{(n-1)n}{2}.$

$\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^n a_k = (a^n) \times q^{[0 + 1 + \cdots + (n-1)]} 
~=~ a^n \times q^{\frac{(n-1)n}{2}}.$

Therefore, 
$\displaystyle q^{20} = a^n \times q^{\frac{(n-1)n}{2}}
~=~ q^{[n(7-n)]} \times q^{\frac{(n-1)n}{2}}
~=~ q^{[n(7-n)] + \frac{(n-1)n}{2}}.$

Therefore, 
$\displaystyle 20 = [n(7-n)] + \frac{(n-1)n}{2}
= (n) \left[(7-n) + \frac{(n-1)}{2}\right] \implies $

$\displaystyle 40 = (n) [(14 - 2n) + (n-1)] = (n) (13 - n)] \implies $

$\displaystyle n^2 - 13n + 40 = 0 \implies
n = \frac{1}{2}\left[13 \pm\sqrt{9}\right] \implies 
n \in \{5,8\}.$

Therefore, there are two candidate values for $(n)$.  It remains to explore each candidate value, to see which one (if any) generates an integer value for $(q)$.  Then, if/when $(n,q,a)$ are successfully determined, the problem's goal can be completed.

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~n = 5}$
Since $\displaystyle q^6 = a_n = aq^{(n-1)} = aq^4,~~
a = q^2.$

Therefore 
$\displaystyle 3^5 = 243 = (a_1)(a_n) = (q^2)[(q^2)(q^4)] = q^8.$

Since $\displaystyle \sqrt[8]{243}$ is not an integer, and $q$ is required to be an integer, the case of $(n=5)$ must be rejected.

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~n = 8}$
Since $\displaystyle q^6 = a_n = aq^{(n-1)} = aq^7,~~
a = q^{(-1)}.$

Therefore 
$\displaystyle 3^5 = 243 = (a_1)(a_n) = 
(q^{(-1)})[q^{(-1)}(q^7)] = q^5.$

Therefore, $\displaystyle 3^5 = q^5 \implies 
q = 3 \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$

Verifying that all the constraints are satisfied:

- $\displaystyle (q,a,n) = \left(3, 3^{(-1)}, 8\right).$
- $\displaystyle a_n = aq^{(n-1)} = 3^{(-1)} 3^7 = 3^6 \implies 
  a_n = q^6.$
- $\displaystyle (a_1 \times \cdots \times a_n) = 
   3^{(-8)} 3^{(28)} = 3^{(20)} = q^{(20)} \implies
  \log_q \{a_1 \times \cdots \times a_n\} = 20.$
- $\displaystyle 3^5 = 243 = 
  \left(3^{(-1)}\right) \times 
  \left[\left(3^{(-1)}\right) 3^7\right]
  = \left(q^{(-1)}\right) \times 
  \left[\left(q^{(-1)}\right) q^7\right]
  = a_1 \times a_n$.

Therefore,
$\displaystyle (q,a,n) = \left(3, 3^{(-1)}, 8\right)$
is verified.

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q^k = \frac{q^n - 1}{q - 1}.$

Therefore,
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k 
= \sum_{k=0}^{7}aq^k 
= a \times \sum_{k=0}^{7}q^k
= 3^{(-1)} \times \sum_{k=0}^{7} 3^k.$

This equals
$\displaystyle ~~3^{(-1)}~~\frac{3^8 - 1}{3 - 1}
= \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{6560}{2}
= \frac{3280}{3}.
$